# Timezone problems with CentOS under VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I have the following problem on a CentOS 6.5 system running under VirtualBox v4.2.4 on Windows 7 Pro SP1.

`date` always prints a UTC time but with the correct timezone shown, e.g. if I run `date` at 12:35 pm I get this:

```
$ date
Fri Mar 20 04:35:45 AWST 2015
```

I've tried the following, none of which worked.  I rebooted after each step.

1. edited `/etc/sysconfig/clock` and changed `UTC=false` to `UTC=true`
2. run `sudo yum erase ntp` as indicated by the VirtualBox bug report [Guest additions confuse clock in linux guest (windows 7 host)](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9679)
3. ran `sudo yum update tzdata`
4. edited `/etc/sysconfig/clock` and removed `UTC=true` completely

I confirmed the following:

- the time and timezone are set correctly on the physical Windows 7 machine
- looked in the Machine settings in VirtualBox; "[Hardware clock in UTC time](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html)" is ticked
- the output of `zdump -v /etc/localtime` is fine
- `env | grep TZ` shows nothing
- `/etc/localtime` was updated by `sudo yum update tzdata`
- `/etc/localtime` and `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Perth` have the same MD5 hash
- `TZ=utc hwclock -r` shows the correct UTC time
- vBox guest additions are not installed (I got no output from `lsmod | grep vboxadd`)

It's worth noting that I looked for where the CentOS boot scripts read `/etc/sysconfig/clock` but couldn't find anything.  This is in contrast to Debian/Ubuntu, which have `/etc/init.d/hwclockfirst.sh` that runs early in the userspace part of the boot process and fixes the system time according to `/etc/default/rcS` which has `UTC=yes` or `UTC=no`.

Comment: See [CentOS Ignoring Timezone and showing UTC](http://serverfault.com/questions/544032/centos-ignoring-timezone-and-showing-utc) question on serverfault.  I tried the suggestions there; let me know if I missed any.

Comment: What does 'date ; date -u' display?  I can't tell if your clock is just off or if your TZ database isn't working.

Comment: "Fri Mar 20 10:36:26 AWST 2015" and "Fri Mar 20 02:36:26 UTC 2015".  As you can see from my `TZ=utc hwclock -r` observation the "hardware" clock from VirtualBox appears to be set to the correct UTC time.

Comment: What do you get from `hwclock --show --debug`?